# Having an issue with GServer in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Okay, so I have a really simple GServer server and an even simpler TCPSocket client (I looked into writing my own async TCPServer, but that turned out to be bigger shoes than I can fill at the moment, so I stumbled across the wonderul GServer).

Now I have this code in my `server.rb`:

```
require 'gserver'
class PServer < GServer
  def initialize
    super(9998)
  end

  def serve client_msg
    for byte in client_msg.bytes
      print byte.chr #Just playing, heh
    end
    print "\n"
    client_msg.print 'Lala'
  end
end

s = PServer.new
s.audit = true
s.debug = true
s.start
s.join
```

So, when I run it, I get no problems (I think) and get this output:

> > [Date and stuff, too long to type] PServer 127.0.0.1:9998 start

The `client.rb` code:

```
require 'socket'
client = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 9998)
client.print "Hi!"
p client.gets
client.close
```

Now, when I run the client, the server reports that it connected, the "Hi!" message. The client 'floats' open (sorry for the lack of a better expression) the whole time, leaving the connection open (however "Lala" is not printed out).

When I run the client again, omitting the line `p client.gets`; the server reports a connection, the "Hi!" and the disconnection of the client. The client just executes and I am returned to the good old prompt. Now, I'm wondering why this is happening. Is it the GServer, the Client, am I doing something dreadfully wrong? Please tell meee. I'm in a metaphorical agony right now.

Thanks for even reading this gigantic text (which is probably full of typos).
xo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong idea about what the parameter to `serve` is.  It's not a message, it is an IO object.  Calling `bytes` on the IO object will try to read it until there is nothing left to read (that is, until the connection is closed).  You should use `gets` for line-based communication, or `read` for binary protocols.

Try replacing your `serve` method with this one:

```
def serve(socket)
  puts socket.gets.chomp
  socket.puts 'Lala'
end
```

Comment: I feel so stupid now! D: Well, thanks. I kind of abandoned the GServer approach. I think I want to swim into the ~jolly~ waters of async servers myself. I'll probably regeret it a few thousand times along the hour, but oh, what one won't do to have fun an learn at the same time.

Comment: @with a dot: don't feel stupid, everyone gets confused.  good luck with your server!